# When installing a new Silverstripe project - mod_rewrite is not enabled?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mamp, silverstripe, mamp-pro

I am using MAMP Pro and for some reason now when I am installing a new silverstripe project it says:

```
URL rewriting support - You need mod_rewrite to use friendly URLs with SilverStripe, but it is not enabled.
```

It never used to do this, and have not had a problem in the past with it.

[image]

I have checked my `httpd.conf` and it is it there, I also checked the 'hosts' tab in MAMP Pro and `mod_rewrite` is checked.

[image]

Any idea as to why it is doing this?

Comment: even though it isn't enabled this is the purpose of the index.php - this will simulate it if you are desperate.  I know that wasn't the question, but I hope it's useful

Comment: I vaguely remember  that some times on mamp I got false negatives on that test with Magento also. Did you actually test that does the rewrite work or not? Also if you reinstalled  MAP, you might just be missing the allow override. See this: http://superuser.com/questions/665723/mamp-htaccess-file-not-working .

Comment: Yeah I tested after the install and it wasn't rewriting the URLs. However testing the next day it worked fine.. So something funky going on there...

Comment: After you install mod_rewrite the apache server needs to be restarted. In linux, it needed to be done as root (command: sudo service apache2 restart ), but not sure about on a mac

Comment: mamp has a button to turn apache off and on

Answer (score 0):

So after abit more testing, it seems as though you need to restart MAMP Pro after you have installed silverstripe to get the URL's to rewrite.